# Multiple file upload isn't sending any data to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to upload multiple file upload.
I have this on client side :

```
        $(document).on( "click", ".save-button", function () {

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('title', $(this).parent().parent().find("#title_place").val());

            $.each($(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
                data.append('file', file);
            });

            $.ajax({type: "POST",
                url: 'save_view.php',
                data: data,
                success : viewSaveCallBack,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
            });
        });
```

I checked all the data in the debuger, and it is working properly. To see this I displayed the value of

```
 $(this).parent().parent().find("#title_place").val()
```

And

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='file']")[0].files
```

Then, when I try to var_dump $_FILES or $_POST on server side, it's empty.
Same thing with a debugger.
[image]
[image]

I tried also with

```
                data.append('files[]', file);
```

When I try to upload a single file (in another input, not exactly the same code), that is working fine.

The html of the input is this one :

```
        <input type=\"file\" multiple directory webkitdirectory allowdirs class=\"form-control input\" id=\"marzipano\">
```

And it is added dynamically to the DOM.

When I upload a single file, that is working fine.

It is not a duplicate of  [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) since I already use a FormData object, and my code is the same as the answer. It is still not working as intended.

Comment: Is your `.save-button` actually submitting the form? This would cancel your AJAX request, if so.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, and I put a breakpoint on the server side and it goes there.

Comment: Are you sure the content type is set correctly? See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @dnFer When using a FormData object, contentType should be set to false .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is working actually, problem was that `post_max_size` in the php.ini was too low.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
var files = $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type='file']")[0].files;

for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
   data.append('file['+i+']', files[i]);
}
```

and in PHP you might get files via `$_POST["file"]`

Comment: Still the same problem. Working for a single file tho.

Comment: What INFO you get in `$_POST`?